# Access Cassandra using Spark Server in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I installed Spark Server on Windows. I also create a maven project to access Cassandra using JavaSparkContext.
Should the Spark server be running in order to run the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mode to use spark server.

Looks like you have setup up a standalone cluster. To use that cluster, of-course it needs to be running. It is like asking can my vehicle run without engine.

But for very small things to test code, you can substitute master to something like "local[2]". It will run your code on the local machine itself with embedded spark instance.